# Replacing youtube iframe src breaks autoplay

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, youtube

I have youtube video iframe in a modal that needs to autoplay when the modal opens, so when the modal is opened, I set the iframe's `src` to the video's embed URL with `?autoplay=1`. This works fine for the first video, any additional videos don't autoplay. The videos load fine, and I can play them. They just don't respect the `autoplay` option.

Here is the code I'm using to replace the iframe's `src`:

```
$modalVideoPreviewIframe.attr('src', sessionPreviewVideoId && `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${sessionPreviewVideoId}?autoplay=1`);
```

I've also tried using jquery's `clone` and `replaceWith` to replace the iframe with a new element before setting its `src`:

```
const $modalVideoPreviewIframeClone = $modalVideoPreviewIframe.attr('src', 'about:blank').clone();
$modalVideoPreviewIframe.replaceWith($modalVideoPreviewIframeClone);
$modalVideoPreviewIframe = $modalVideoPreviewIframeClone;
$modalVideoPreviewIframe.attr('src', sessionPreviewVideoId && `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${sessionPreviewVideoId}?autoplay=1`);
```

Comment: why don't use [youtube iframe api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)?

Comment: @gaetanoM I didn't think I would need it. I'm adding it now because I've already spent too much time on this silly video issue.

Comment: Great. The YouTube SDK isn't working. `new Player` never emits `onReady` or `onError`. I guess I'm off to write another question..

Comment: do you get any error in the console?

Comment: No. I figured it out. It was silently failing because I was passing `#my-id` instead of `my-id`. Expecting id strings instead of query strings is such a gross practice. Anyway, I'm closing this question because my issue is resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using the [YouTube iframe SDK](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference):

```
$('#session-modal-video').replaceWith('<div id="session-modal-video"></div>');
const player = new YT.Player('session-modal-video', {
  height: '390',
  width: '640',
  videoId: sessionPreviewVideoId,
  events: {
    'onReady'() {
      if(autoplay) {
        player.playVideo();
      }
    },
    'onError'(error) {
      console.log('Failed to create Youtube video player', error)
    }
  }
});
```